# Where are the Winery types indexed?

Tags: haskell, serialization

I want to build an alternate Winery schema decoder. So I had a look at some of the encoded schemas:

```
*Codec.Winery> B.unpack $ serialiseSchema $ schema (Proxy :: Proxy Void)
[4,5,0]
*Codec.Winery> B.unpack $ serialiseSchema $ schema (Proxy :: Proxy Bool)
[4,6]
*Codec.Winery> B.unpack $ serialiseSchema $ schema (Proxy :: Proxy Int)
[4,16]
*Codec.Winery> B.unpack $ serialiseSchema $ schema (Proxy :: Proxy Integer)
[4,16]
*Codec.Winery> B.unpack $ serialiseSchema $ schema (Proxy :: Proxy Void)
[4,5,0]
*Codec.Winery> B.unpack $ serialiseSchema $ schema (Proxy :: Proxy ())
[4,3,0]
```

I know the first number is the schema version. I understand that the Int can be encoded as an Integer since it is strictly smaller. But what about the others?

I tried to compare it to the indexed of the types mentioned in [`bookstrapSchema`](https://github.com/fumieval/winery/blob/ef98e528cd672b5ee6335cbd3f42a23c7e601058/src/Codec/Winery/Base.hs#L163) but they don't seem to match.

How can I make sense of these numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They match, but some take arguments.  Ignoring the version number `4`, the encoding `[5,0]` means an `SVariant` with zero alternatives, basically a sum type with no constructors, AKA `Void`:

```
data Void
```

On the other hand `[3,0]` means an `SProduct` with zero fields, namely a type with a single nullary constructor, AKA `()`:

```
data () = ()
```

I'd suggest looking at sum and product types other than these "degenerate" ones, and studying the output of `pretty`-printing the schemas alongside their serializations:

```
import Codec.Winery
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Data.Proxy
import Prettyprinter

main = do
  let s = schema (Proxy :: Proxy (Either Int String))
  print $ B.unpack . serialiseSchema $ s
  print $ pretty s
```

The encoding and pretty-printed schema here are:

```
[4,5,2,4,76,101,102,116,3,1,16,5,82,105,103,104,116,3,1,2,7]
Left Integer | Right [Char]
```

which means:

```
[4                       -- version 4
,5,2                     -- SVariant with 2 alternatives, namely:
  ,4,76,101,102,116      --   4-character constructor "Left" for
    ,3,1                 --     SProduct with 1 field
      ,16                --       consisting of an SInteger
  ,5,82,105,103,104,116  --   5-character constructor "Right" for
    ,3,1                 --     SProduct with 1 field
      ,2                 --       consisting of an SVector
        ,7]              --         of SChar
```