# How do fixpoint, variable, let and tag schema constructors work in Winery?

Tags: haskell, serialization

I had previously asked [where the Winery types are indexed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65856745/309483). I noticed that in the serialization for the schema for `Bool`, which is `[4,6]`, the 4 is the version number, and 6 is the index of SBool in [SchemaP](https://github.com/fumieval/winery/blob/ef98e528cd672b5ee6335cbd3f42a23c7e601058/src/Codec/Winery/Base.hs#L90). I verified the hypothesis using other "primitive" types like Integer (serialization: 16), Double (18), Text (20). Also, `[Bool]` will be `SVector SBool`, serialized to `[4,2,6]`, which makes sense: the 2 is for SVector, the 6 is for SBool.

But SchemaP also contains constructors that I don't intuitively see how are used: SFix, SVar, STag and SLet. What are they, and which type would I need to construct the schema for, to see them used? Why is SLet at the end, but SFix at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SFix` looks like a µ quantifier for a [recursive type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type). The type µx. T is the type T where *x* refers to the whole type µx. T. For example, a list `data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)` can be represented as L(a) = µr. 1 + a × r, where the recursive occurrence of the type is replaced with the variable r. You could probably see this with a recursive user-defined type like `data BinTree a = Leaf | Branch a (BinTree a) (BinTree a)`.

This encoding doesn’t explicitly include a variable name, because the next constructor `SVar` specifies that “`SVar n` refers to the `n`th innermost fixpoint”, where `n` is an `Int` in the synonym `type Schema = SchemaP Int`. This is a [De Bruijn index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index). If you had some nested recursive types like µx. µy. … = `SFix (SFix …)`, then the inner variable would be referenced as `SVar 0` and the outer one as `SVar 1` within the body `…`. This “relative” notation means you can freely reorganise terms without worrying about having to rename variables for [capture-avoiding substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Capture-avoiding_substitutions).

`SLet` is a `let` binding, and since it’s specified as `SLet !(SchemaP a) !(SchemaP a)`, I presume that `SLet e1 e2` is akin to `let x = e1 in e2`, where the variable is again implicit. So I suspect this may be a deficiency of the docs, and `SVar` can also refer to `Let`-bound variables. I don’t know how they use this constructor, but it could be used to make sharing explicit in the schema.

Finally, `STag` appears to be a way to attach extra “tag” metadata within the schema, in some way that’s specific to the library.

The ordering of these constructors might be maintained for compatibility with earlier versions, so adding new constructors at the end would avoid disturbing the encoding, and I figure the `STag` and `SLet` constructors at the end were simply added later.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Where did you get `isBigSchema` from? It seems to have [been removed](https://github.com/fumieval/winery/commit/84e2e68e7ec13ca587d8ffee0a67d25b278c52be) in 2019.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: Ah thanks, I was just skimming the Git history for when these features were added, but I guess that part has been changed since.